# Is it possible to prevent ogr2ogr from generating a shapefile if no records are returned from the given intersection?

Tags: gdal, shapefile, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr, intersection

I am generating shapefiles from a geodatabase file with ogr2ogr via the spatialite dialect using the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" ./clipped.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ST_Intersects(SHAPE, GeomFromText('POLYGON ((46.93 -17.48, 46.91 -17.55, 47.01 -17.56, 47.01 -17.46, 46.93 -17.48))'))" ./geodatabase_file.gdb
```

The command itself works exactly as expected - returning only the records that are intersected by the given spatial query.

There are however, times when no records are returned by the intersection. When this happens empty shapefiles are generated that contain no entries. Is there a way to prevent ogr2ogr from generating files if no records are returned from a provided intersection?

Comment: With ogr2ogr, I do not believe it is possible. The utility creates the shapefile first and then adds features into it. You need to use for example python for deleting the shapefile if it remains empty.  Or you can run ogrinfo and check if it contains a row `Feature Count: 0`.